# c++ Windows API recursive search is not returning expected directory

Tags: c++, winapi, recursion

I am currently trying to write a program that recursively searches for a file using the utilities present within windows.h.  When I execute the following code, the file path keeps getting added to the last file path searched, yet the folders aren't searched and the handle isn't flagged for being invalid. I have been stewing over this for a few days.  Why isn't this recursively searching?
Edit:  Corrected code to use bitwise comparisons.  Same error is occurring.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h> // Microsoft Windows’ main library. 
#include <tchar.h> // Needed for _TEXT macro. 
#include "Strsafe.h" // Microsoft's library for secure strings.

using namespace std;
typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR, *PWSTR;
int layer = 0;

int recursionFindAbsraction(LPWSTR Dir, LPWSTR FilNam, LPWSTR filePath);
//original directory, new directory with *.* attached
//new directory with entire directory, new entire directory with *.* attached
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t holder[MAX_PATH];//using this instead of string
    wchar_t direct[MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t filePath[MAX_PATH];

    wcout << "Please enter the directory you wish to search: " << endl;
    wcin >> direct;
    wcout << direct << endl;


    wcout << "Please enter the filename (program will automatically seach for all files like it): " << endl;
    wcin >> holder;
    wcout << holder << endl;

    recursionFindAbsraction(direct, holder, filePath);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;

}

int recursionFindAbsraction(LPWSTR Dir, LPWSTR FilNam, LPWSTR filePath){
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW ptrFileData;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    BOOL bGetNext = true;

    wchar_t newDir[MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t newDir2[MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t filePathHolder[MAX_PATH];

    //add slash then put directory into new variable, newDir
    StringCchCatW(Dir, MAX_PATH, _TEXT("\\"));

    //Here, we split the path to avoid appending *.* to the current directory
    StringCchCopyW(filePathHolder, MAX_PATH, Dir);
    StringCchCopyW(newDir, MAX_PATH, Dir);
    StringCchCopyW(newDir2, MAX_PATH, Dir);
    StringCchCatW(newDir2, MAX_PATH, _TEXT("*.*"));
    hFile = FindFirstFile(newDir2, &ptrFileData);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("FindFirstFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        //return 0;
    }

    while (bGetNext){

        if ((ptrFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) != 0)
        {
            int setLoop = (ptrFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
            wcout << " file Attribute bitwise: " << setLoop;
            wcout << "file hidden " << endl;
            int counter = 0; counter++;
            wcout << "counter: " << counter << endl;
            wcout << "string compare: " << _wcsicmp(ptrFileData.cFileName, _TEXT("..")) << endl;
            wcout << "filename: " << ptrFileData.cFileName << endl;
            Sleep(100);
            /*
            if (_wcsicmp(ptrFileData.cFileName, _TEXT(".")) == 0){
                wcout << "Breaking1. " << endl;
                continue;
            }
            if (_wcsicmp(ptrFileData.cFileName, _TEXT("..")) == 0){
                wcout << "Breaking2. " << endl;
                continue;
            }*/
        }

        else
        {
            if (_wcsicmp(ptrFileData.cFileName, FilNam) == 0){
                wcout << "The first file found is: " << ptrFileData.cFileName << endl;
                //_tprintf(TEXT("The first file found is %s\n"), ptrFileData.cFileName);
                FindClose(hFile);
                //getchar();
                break;
            }
            if ((((ptrFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0)) && ((ptrFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0))
            {//must check to see if folder
                layer++;
                wcout << "Layer: " << layer << endl;
                ptrFileData.cFileName;
                //when this gets called because it's a folder, the name
                //gets added to the wrong directory
                StringCchCatW(newDir, MAX_PATH, ptrFileData.cFileName);
                wcout << " newDir/fulldir: " << newDir<< endl;
                //resolves full path name at this point
                wcout << "filePathHolder from last else: " << filePathHolder << endl;
                wcout << "filename: " << ptrFileData.cFileName << endl;

                recursionFindAbsraction(newDir, FilNam, filePath);

            }

        }
        wcout << "&ptrFileData: " << &ptrFileData << endl;
        wcout << "hFile: " << hFile << endl;
        bGetNext = FindNextFile(hFile, &ptrFileData);
        wcout << " exit: " << bGetNext<< endl;
    }
    FindClose(hFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `FindFirstFile` always returns entries for `.` and `..` before anything else, so your test for `if (_wcsicmp(ptrFileData.cFileName, _TEXT(".")) == 0)` will cause you to break out of the loop immediately.

Comment: You may also want to test attributes using `&` rather than `==` since it's quite common to have multiple attribute flags set at once.

Comment: I haven't work with an `WIN32_FIND_DATAW` structure/class, but I'm sure that you shouldn't compare the `.dwFileAttributes` property with `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` directly, as the same fashion you shouldn't compare it with `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` directly. I can bet my hat that those are Flags in the dwFileAttributes bit-field (or int) and you should check if each bit is enabled or not in the dwFileAttributes field. Like `((ptrFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)!=0) && ((ptrFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)==0)` but better if you check more info on that...

Comment: The code *can't* work in general for a ANSI character set build. So the `T` stuff is just added verbosity and complication. Besides, you won't find a Windows 9x installation to try the ANSI build on.

Comment: You keep appending to `newDir`, so the second directory you find will append after the first directory. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of recursive search. Note, it uses `do{...}while(...);` which makes it easier to skip to the end of the loop

```
void findfile_recursive(const std::wstring &folder, const std::wstring &filename, std::vector<std::wstring> &files)
{
    std::wstring wildcard = folder + L"\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(wildcard.c_str(), &fd);
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;
    do
    {
        if (wcscmp(fd.cFileName, L".") == 0 || wcscmp(fd.cFileName, L"..") == 0)
            continue;
        std::wstring path = folder + L"\\" + std::wstring(fd.cFileName);

        if (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            findfile_recursive(path, filename, files);
        else if (_wcsicmp(fd.cFileName, filename.c_str()) == 0)
            files.push_back(path);

    } while (FindNextFile(handle, &fd));
    FindClose(handle);
}

int _tmain(int, wchar_t*[])
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> files;
    findfile_recursive(L"c:\\test", L"file.txt", files);
    for (auto file : files)
        std::wcout << file << endl;
}
```

You can change your function to use do/while. When calling the function recursively, make sure it has the right argument. `newDir` changes in the loop, you can't reuse it as a reference. Use `Dir` instead.

```
int recursionFindAbsraction(LPWSTR Dir, LPWSTR FilNam, LPWSTR filePath)
{
    ...
    //while (bGetNext)***
    do
    {
        if (wcscmp(ptrFileData.cFileName, L".") == 0 || wcscmp(ptrFileData.cFileName, L"..") == 0)
            continue;

        if (ptrFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
            continue;//***skip hidden files and directories

        if (ptrFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            //***wrong redirection:
            //StringCchCatW(newDir, MAX_PATH, ptrFileData.cFileName);

            //***change to:
            StringCchCopyW(newDir, MAX_PATH, Dir);
            StringCchCatW(newDir, MAX_PATH, ptrFileData.cFileName);
            recursionFindAbsraction(newDir, FilNam, filePath);
        }
        else if (_wcsicmp(ptrFileData.cFileName, FilNam) == 0)
        {
            std::wcout << "The first file found is: " << Dir << ptrFileData.cFileName << endl;
        }

    } while (FindNextFile(hFile, &ptrFileData));//***

    FindClose(hFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes!  Logically that's what I was trying to do but I got lost in my control statements.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey sorry for kicking an old question, but ‘FindFirstFile‘ requires that “the user must have access permissions to the root and all subdirectories on the path”. But how can I handle a case where I don’t have permissions for a single file in the directory?