# Recursive function to search Windows directories in C | Win32 API

Tags: c, recursion, winapi, filesystems, file-search

I cannot get this to work. It either still searches "." endlessly on some directory within my Windows directory, or it will continuously append ".\" to the path it's searching. I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226628/c-windows-api-recursive-search-is-not-returning-expected-directory), but I don't want to just copy and paste and am also wondering if I can do this without a do-while loop. I am learning the Win32 API as we speak. Can anyone advise what is going wrong? The function should return the path to the file OR directory being search. Right now, I just have it printing it for simplicity.

EDIT ----
I got it to work, maybe inefficiently, it does indeed find the specified file passed in, but continues to search until it's exhausted all options. How can I have it pass the recursive calls back up the chain when the file in question is found? I thought it would be to run the loop on the condition of a recursive call returning a certain value, but not sure how to implement.

OLD CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>


void findFile(STRSAFE_LPWSTR fileToFind, STRSAFE_LPWSTR directory) {

    HANDLE hFindFile;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW data;
    wchar_t pathBuffer[MAX_PATH];

    // append the wildcard
    StringCchPrintfW(pathBuffer, MAX_PATH, L"%ws\\*", directory);
    
    
    hFindFile = FindFirstFileW(pathBuffer, &data);
    printf("File/directory name: %ws\n", data.cFileName);

    if (hFindFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("%s\n", "Invalid File Handle was returned.");
        return;
    }

    int running = 1;
    while (running != 0) {
        // skip directory links
        if ((wcsncmp(data.cFileName, L".", 1) == 0) || (wcsncmp(data.cFileName, L"..", 2) == 0)) {
            running = FindNextFileW(hFindFile, &data);
            continue;
        }

        // check if file/directory was found
        if (wcscmp(data.cFileName, fileToFind) == 0) {
            printf("%ws\\%ws\n", directory, data.cFileName);
            return;
        }

        // check if current file is a directory
        if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {

            StringCchPrintfW(pathBuffer, MAX_PATH, L"%ws\\%ws", directory, data.cFileName);

            printf("Searching %ws...\n", pathBuffer);
            // recurse
            
            printf("Current path buffer: %ws\n", pathBuffer);
            findFile(fileToFind, pathBuffer);
        }
        running = FindNextFileW(hFindFile, &data);
    }
        
    FindClose(hFindFile);
}



int main(void) {

    findFile(L"white_elephant.py", L"C:");

    return 0;
}
```

NEW CODE

```
int findFile(wchar_t *fileToFind, wchar_t *startDirectory) {
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW data;
    HANDLE hFindFile;
    
    int worked = 1;
    // clear buffer
    wchar_t pathBuffer[MAX_PATH];
    // append wildcard to directory
    printf("Current starting directory: %ws\n", startDirectory);
    StringCchPrintfW(pathBuffer, MAX_PATH, L"%ws\\*", startDirectory);
    printf("Current buffer: %ws\n", pathBuffer);

    // grab first result
    hFindFile = FindFirstFileW(pathBuffer, &data);

    // verify proper return handle
    if (hFindFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("%ws\n", L"Invalid return handle... Aborting.");
        return 1;
    }

    while (worked != 0) {
        // check if file was found
        if (wcscmp(data.cFileName, fileToFind) == 0) { 
            StringCchPrintfW(pathBuffer, MAX_PATH, L"%ws\\%ws", startDirectory, data.cFileName);
            printf("File found at: %ws\n", pathBuffer);
            return 1;
        }
        // check if a directory
        if ((data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && !(data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)) {

            // check for . and .. links
            if ( (wcscmp(data.cFileName, L".") != 0) && (wcscmp(data.cFileName, L"..") != 0) ) {
                printf("Found: %ws\n", data.cFileName);
                // modify buffer to have it be the starting point for the recursive call
                StringCchPrintfW(pathBuffer, MAX_PATH, L"%ws\\%ws", startDirectory, data.cFileName);
                printf("Recursing into: %ws\n", pathBuffer);
                findFile(fileToFind, pathBuffer);
            }

        }
        worked = FindNextFileW(hFindFile, &data);
    }

    return 1;



}


int main(void) {

    findFile(L"some_file", L"C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use less stack space than this in a recursive function that enumerates a disk volume.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: He means a buffer of size `MAX_PATH` in a function that can recurse a hundred times is pushing it. This one buffer consumes more than half the total of the default stack.

Comment: Got it, so it would be smarter, to declare the buffer once and keep overwriting it?

Comment: That's what I did yes.

Comment: @Joshua I wasn't able to figure it out without screwing up the next recursive call, the buffer didn't seem to clear all the way. Anyhow, I revised my question with a new issue, returning when the file is found, instead of continuing to search the system.